# Add value to array using Bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops

I have written the following script ,

```
#!/bin/bash
My_File=Image.csv
Value=YES
cat "$My_File" | while IFS=, read first last
do
    echo "first='$first' last='$last'"
    if [ "$last" == "$Value" ];
       then
       echo Match_Found
       echo $first
       array+=("$first")
       echo $first is Added
    fi
done
echo (${#array[@]})
```

It dosenot add any value to the array , Could someone point out to the issue .
The Input is as follow ,

```
FA_2015-01_666,NO
FA_2015-01_777,YES
FA_2015-01_888,NO
FA_2015-01_999,YES
FA_2015-01_555,YES
```

Comment: `array+={"$first")` what happens when you change the last `)` to a `}` ?

Comment: Better yet, change the `{` to a `(`.

Comment: array+=($first) - This gaives same result , 0 and so does this array+=("$first")

Comment: What i want to know is why it even runs with unmatched braces

Comment: Actually that was an error when i copied over the code - My mistake ,on checking the Terminal , it appears to be correct

Comment: Does `echo $first is Added` trigger at all ? I don't have a terminal to test your script

Comment: I also tried declaring an empty array array=() , but its still gives out 0

Comment: You are running it in a subshell by piping in from cat. Don't do that.

Comment: All the echo works perfect in the code ..except the array push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect the file in, don't pipe from cat or the loop is run in a subshell and everything in it is lost when it ends.

```
#!/bin/bash
My_File="Image.csv"
Value=YES
while IFS=, read first last
do
    if [ "$last" == "$Value" ];
       then
       echo Match_Found
       echo $first
       array+=("$first")
       echo $first is Added
    fi
done < "$My_File"
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

Comment: This works perfect , i was not aware of the cons mentioned by you.Thanks a lot for quick debug

Comment: @AsheshNair No Problem. Just remember any variables set in a pipeline are lost when it ends :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done some bash coding in some time, but it should be like this (The way i do it):

```
#our table to insert an item to
table=( )
tableLength=${#table[@]}

#inserting items
table[$tableLength]="foo"
#you have to refresh this variable everytime
tableLength=${#table[@]}
table[$tableLength]="bar"
#or you can do this without refreshing the length variable
table[${#table[@]}]="foobar"
```

I recommend you use:

```
table=()
table[${#table[@]}]="item!"
```

using `#` as the length, and `table[@]` to display all items, so it gets the length of the array and sets an item to the length of an array or table

Comment: also tables and arrays are the same thing

Comment: This is tangibly related to the question and doesn't provide and answer to what OP is actually asking.

Comment: alright, what's the fun in coding if you just copy/paste the answers, this is the way i learned, so I thought it would help.

Comment: Who's copy and pasted anything ? I think the fun is actually solving problems instead of posting slightly related, personal preferences for coding. I honestly don't understand what your answer is trying to achieve.

Comment: Well if you have actually read the answer instead of downvoting, the comments are pretty clear to me, I'm no scientist but I think i know what `#inserting items` means.

Comment: Cool, don't think you need to be a scientist to post a relevant answer either. All you have posted is another(IMO much worse) way of adding elements to an array, which OP was already capable of.

Comment: Look at the title of the question. How is my answer irrelevant?

Comment: If he knew how to add elements to an array, then why post such an ambiguous title question?

Comment: You would know if you read the question... The title is just to give an idea of what the question is about...

Comment: @User112638726 All ill say to that is make it the title count, i cant just post an irrelevent title and then post something different below it, now im not intentionally trying to offend the op in anyway...

Comment: @EEVV I think the title is very important since it's what has bigger weight when searching for a question. This was my top hit when searching how to insert into arrays and this "non related" answer was a solution to my problem. Should I've read the original question and dismiss answers when compared to my needs?